# Perguntas para saciar curiosidade

Tags: debate

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta sobre como verificar se um método existe usando C#.
 A intenção da pergunta era apenas saciar minha curiosidade, em uma aplicação console que eu estava fazendo, porém um usuário comentou pedindo um uso prático do que eu estava pedindo, nas seguintes palavras:

> "Precisaria mostrar um caso onde isso é útil"

Vale ressaltar que não tenho nada contra o usuário, nenhum tipo de mágoa, e ele provavelmente vai ver essa pergunta, eu só não citei o nome dele pois não sei como entrar em contato com alguém diretamente aqui no Stack Overflow e não acho certo citar alguém sem antes pedir a devida permissão.

Então, não sabendo exemplificar um caso real e útil aonde os conhecimentos provenientes de eventuais respostas para a minha pergunta, eu a exclui.

A dúvida ficou pipocando na minha cabeça: É errado eu fazer uma pergunta, por mais objetiva que seja, apenas para saciar minha curiosidade?

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Posta o link da pergunta, tem problema não, pelo que vi do comentário, foi bem amistoso, então acredito que divulgar o link não causará desanvenças.

Comment: @jbueno eu coloquei no final do post: A dúvida ficou pipocando na minha cabeça: É errado eu fazer uma pergunta, por mais objetiva que seja, apenas para saciar minha curiosidade?

Comment: Qual a pergunta que você fez no site principal e não a pergunta aqui =) poste o link para vermos por favor.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário ele quis dizer "qual a pergunta que gerou sua duvida aqui no meta"

Comment: Ah sim, sinto muito ahahaha me falta café, vou postar aqui nos comentários

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194724/verificar-exist%C3%AAncia-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c/194736#194736

Comment: O comentário não necessariamente signifique que a pergunta não é boa, e sim pode servir como um alerta pra não usar na prática o objeto da pergunta. Não vi a postagem ainda, mas precisa tomar cuidado com isso. UPDATE: depois do refresh apareceu o link nos comments

Comment: A ler o comentário, não me parece objeção à pergunta, e sim ao uso prático da técnica. E, adicionalmente, é o tipo de coisa que quando você contextualiza, pode originar respostas com solução melhor do que a buscada, como descrito no [Problema XY](/q/499). No seu caso, como é curiosidade, mencionar isto lá facilita pra quem responder não ficar procurando alternativas para o problema. Não posso falar por outros usuários, mas eu quando respondo normalmente não me limito à resposta "seca", sempre que possível costumo questionar e propor alternativas sempre que possível (quando sei a finalidade)

Comment: Concordo que não parece objeção! Mas eu não soube, como eu disse, responder ao pedido dele de dar um uso real da pergunta. E como é um usuário de considerável influência no site, eu achei que aquele fosse um requisito para a pergunta

Comment: @ArturoTemplário fez bem em vir tirar sua dúvida. Sendo dentro do escopo do site e objetiva, a pergunta por mera curiosidade não tem problema. Mas fica a dica de contextualizar sempre o máximo que puder, não pela "obrigação", mas para enriquecer o post e as respostas (quando aplicável, claro).

Answer (score 8):

Você pode ver que [tipos de perguntas podem ser feitas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Pode [ver diversas dúvidas sobre reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+reflex%C3%A3o).

Aquele pergunta que eu comentei isso pedia algo completamente desnecessário de fazer. Ou precisa de uma pergunta genérica sobre reflexão, e já tem várias sobre isso no site ou precisaria ser um problema específico que está tendo. Conforme o primeiro *link* precisa ser um problema prático, algo que seja real, mesmo que por curiosidade, o que a pergunta pedia era algo completamente sem sentido e desnecessário, então nenhuma resposta ali faria sentido, tanto que foi dada uma resposta fazendo algo sem necessidade alguma. Eu queria saber o motivo porque se fosse um problema genérico de uso da reflexão provavelmente seria duplicata de alguma pergunta existente.

O que eu estava tentando fazer é achar um eixo para a pergunta para tentar responder adequadamente ou definir uma duplicata. Meu objetivo era salvar a pergunta. Talvez a resposta fosse que não é necessário e porque, mas precisava de mais informações.

Então pode fazer pergunta para saciar a curiosidade, mas ela precisa ser clara, precisa mostrar um caso bem definido, ter um foco.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado!